# How interpret a residual plot

Tags: r, data-visualization, regression

I am trying to build a multiple regression model as a part of a beginner's course.

I came up a model after selection and conducted diagnosis. The picture below is the residual plot (x = fitted y = residuals). I cannot understand what this means and how to interpret it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did not know there is separate platform to ask this question!

Comment: The definition residual = observed response $-$ fitted implies that distinct values of the observed fall on distinct lines with slope $-1$, as any particular value follows residual = particular $-$ fitted. So, it seems your response is bounded and by the way that plain regression is a poor choice therefore. Tell us more about your response (outcome, dependent variable), notably its actual and possible minimum and maximum.